# Add extension for multiple files, based on their types

Tags: bash, rename

I know that there are many questions about adding extension to a multiple files. But none of them could get my job done.

I have a huge list of images without extension, most of them are png, but there are jpg files also and maybe tiff.

How could I rename them correctly?

Comment: Related: [How to add file extensions based on file type on Linux/Unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/352837)

Comment: I need bash not python.

Comment: You're right. edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```bash
for f in /some/dir/*; do
    type="$( file -bi -- "$f" )"
    case "${type%%;*}" in
        image/jpeg) ext=jpg ;;
        image/png)  ext=png ;;
        image/tiff) ext=tiff ;;
        *) printf '%s: %s: unknown file type\n' "${0##*/}" "$f" >&2; ext='' ;;
    esac
    if [ -n "$ext" ]; then mv -n -- "$f" "${f}.${ext}"; fi
done
```

Comment: Please note this answer has been edited since I posted it.  I disagree with the edit.  Sadly, I can no longer delete my answer, since it has been already accepted. _shrug_

Comment: You should also revert the `${f%.*}` back to `${f}`. Nobody wants their `photo.of.bigfoot` renamed to `photo.of.jpg`. ;-)

Comment: @Dubu: Right, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Another way with `exiftool`:

```
exiftool -r -ext '' '-filename<$filename.$filetype' .
```

this `r`ecursively renames all image files without extension under current directory `.` to `filename.TYPE` where `TYPE` is `JPEG`, `PNG`, `TIFF` etc.

Or, to rename only files of type JPEG/PNG/TIFF that have no extension:

```
exiftool -if '$filetype eq "JPEG"' -filename=%f.jpg \
-execute -if '$filetype eq "PNG"' -filename=%f.png \
-execute -if '$filetype eq "TIFF"' -filename=%f.tiff \
-common_args -r -ext '' .
```

Comment: Thank you. Very elegant. However it requires installing `libimage-exiftool-perl`

Comment: I mean that I have a huge number of files. And yes, all of them are without extension.

Comment: @OsamaAbbas - got it. In that case you already have lcd047's working solution that doesn't require additional tools.

Comment: @don_crissti - assuming the extension is present but incorrect, how would someone use your solution to rename the file to the correct extension? For example, lets assume x.png is really x.jpg but simply has the wrong extension. How can I use your solution to rename the file to x.jpg?

Comment: ok, I got it I just removed the -ext '', you were using that to express a lack of a file extension. Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question, but if you want to know which image type (PNG, JPEG, etc) is a specific file, you can use the `file` command:

```
file myimage.xxx

myimage.xxx: PNG image data, 837 x 814, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know file but my question is how to use its result to rename multiple files.